# join two tables and limit results by an ordered list

Tags: mysql

problem:

given is a table with language support (translations)

a user can configure a list of languages (order is priority)

now i have to get all rows which are part of `app` and the `locale` is in the list of preconfigured languages for a user;

only ONE result per `property` shall be returned

so for example the user configured `de-AT, de-DE, de, en` as preferred user settings
NOTE: not all values need to be defined!

the user requests all data for `app='test'`
the expected result is

```
 property, value
('father', 'Oida'),
('lastName', 'Nachname'),
```

Table for Multilanguage Data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `i18n` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `app` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    `locale` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    `property` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    `value` VARCHAR(1000) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

example values in `i18n` table

```
INSERT INTO `i18n` (app, locale, property, value)
VALUES 
('test', 'de-AT', 'father', 'Oida'),
('test', 'de-DE', 'father', 'Papa'),
('test', 'de', 'father', 'Vater'),
('test', 'en', 'father', 'father'),
('test', 'fr', 'father', 'père'),
('test', 'en','lastName', 'last name'),
('test', 'de','lastName', 'Nachname'),
('test', 'fr','lastName', 'nom de famille'),
```

my idea was to put user config into its own table (if its possible without this it would be even better)

Table for User Config

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `i18n_cfg` (
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user` VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    `locale` VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    `priority` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

example values in `i18n_cfg` table

```
INSERT INTO `i18n_cfg` (locale, user, priority)
VALUES 
('de-AT', 'lm', 1),
('de-DE', 'lm', 2),
('de', 'lm', 3),
('en', 'lm', 4),
('de', 'hr', 1),
('en','hr', 2),
```

i'm not really getting to a point
i get only one result or way too much

NOTE using mysql 5.7 (if it would work on sql server too - with minor changes - it would be perfect)

Comment: please fix this: INSERT INTO `i18n_cfg` (user, locale, priority) should be INSERT INTO `i18n_cfg` (locale, user, priority)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to join table with priority and use ROW_NUMBER function to sort rows for each property, then you just need to leave rows with row number = 1:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT t1.property
,t1.value
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.property ORDER BY t2.priority) AS rn
FROM i18n t1
JOIN i18n_cfg t2 ON t1.locale = t2.locale
WHERE t1.app = 'test' 
AND t2.user = 'lm'
)
SELECT property, value
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

solution without window functions and variables:

```
SELECT t1.property 
,(SELECT t2.value
  FROM i18n AS t2
  JOIN i18n_cfg AS t3 ON t2.locale = t3.locale
  WHERE t2.property = t1.property
  AND t2.app = 'test'
  AND t3.user = 'lm'
  ORDER BY t3.priority
  LIMIT 1) AS value
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT property
FROM i18n
WHERE app = 'test'
) AS t1
```

link to dbfiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf1d3f4757c3d84d3f5ad2bea0966a3c

Comment: @lumo you can use a sub-query instead of CTE. Also MySQL 5.7 doesn't support window functions and you need to emulate ROW_NUMBER, you can find how to do it here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58645949/emulating-partition-over-with-mysql-5-7 and here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895110/row-number-in-mysql

Comment: @lumo Actually the most popular RDBMSs support window functions for over decade, even MySQL added support of ROW_NUMBER more than 3 years ago. You don't need any variables if you have window functions to solve this task and I don't think they are complicated. Doesn't this query look easy?